# How can I access a shadowed definition in Forth?

Tags: forth, gforth

When a word is redefined, is it possible to access the old word?

Imagine there is a word `foo` defined and redefined

```
: foo ( n -- 2*n ) 2* ;  ok
: foo ( n -- 2*n+1 ) foo 1+ ; redefined foo   ok
10 foo . 21  ok
```

`foo` here executed both definitions.

Is it possible to execute the first definition ("second-foo")?

```
21 second-foo . 42 ok
```

To `see` it?

```
see second-foo
: foo
  2* ; ok
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to access a shadowed definition is to create a synonym for the definition before creating a new definition with the same name.

```
synonym old-foo foo
: foo ... ;
```

Another way is to use introspection tools, namely the word [`traverse-wordlist`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/TRAVERSE-WORDLIST). Using this word we can define a word `find-name-nth-in` that is similar to the standardized word `find-name-in ( c-addr u wid -- nt|0 )`, but it finds n-th shadowed word, as follows:

```
: find-name-nth-in ( c-addr1 u1 u wid -- nt|0 )
  >r 1+
  [: ( sd u nt -- sd u true | sd nt 0 false )
    2>r 2dup r@ name>string compare if rdrop r> true exit then
    r> r> 1- dup if nip then dup 0<>
  ;] r> traverse-wordlist ( sd u | sd nt 0 )
  if 2drop 0 exit then nip nip
;
```

This `find-name-nth-in` word returns an *nt* for the word that has the given name in the given word list, and **after which exactly *u* words with the same name (case-sensitively) were defined in the word list**, or 0 otherwise.

A test case:

```
: ?name ( nt|0 -- nt ) dup 0= -13 and throw ;

: foo ." old" ;
: foo ." new" ;

"foo" 0 forth-wordlist find-name-nth-in ?name name>interpret execute
\ prints "new"

"foo" 1 forth-wordlist find-name-nth-in ?name name>interpret execute
\ prints "old"
```

In Gforth the word [`xt-see`](https://gforth.org/manual/Examining-compiled-code.html) can be used as:

```
"foo" 1 forth-wordlist find-name-nth-in ?name name>interpret xt-see
```